# Rotate rectangle on screen

Tags: c++, gdi+, rotation

I'm using GDI+ to try to draw a rectangle on the screen and rotate it 45 degrees.
Here's the code I'm using

```
Pen RedPen(Color(255, 255, 0, 0), 4);

HDC screenDC = GetDC(NULL);
Graphics graphics(screenDC);

graphics.RotateTransform(45);
graphics.DrawRectangle(&RedPen, 150, 150, 50, 50);
```

The rectangle rotates, but it's position moves in a circle the more it rotates.
I'm pretty sure this is because I'm rotating the center of the screen, instead of the center of the rectangle?
So how would I rotate it around the center of the rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it's not rotating around the center of the Rectangle as you noticed. So you need to translate the object after it's rotated.

```
        e->Graphics->RotateTransform(degrees);
        e->Graphics->TranslateTransform(posX, posY, MatrixOrder::Append);
        e->Graphics->DrawRectangle(gcnew Pen( Color::Blue,3.0f ),  -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
```

**degrees** is the amount you want to rotate your rectangle. **posX** and **posY** are the position where you want to draw it in screen.

Also you need to make sure you pass MatrixOrder::Append otherwise the order of the Transform might be changed and that will apply the Translation before rotating (giving you a similar effect to what you are seeing)